# How to remove filename from Select-String results with Context option in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Without `-Context` option I could easily choose just `select line` without `filename` from `Select-String` results. But this is not a case when I use `Select-String -Context x,y` option.

Is there a way to hide filename from Context lines?

Answer (score 7):

No, you can also run `Select-String -context x,y ... | select line`, providing `-context` parameter to `Select-String`, but you'll just omit the relevant context altogether in your output.

You seem to desire to override the default behavior of `MatchInfo::ToString()` writing filename with lines. You can do like this:

```
Select-String -Context x,y .... |
  % {$_.context.precontext;$_.line;$_.context.postcontext}
```

This will output a set of strings with an unmarked matching line, but this should give you a start on formatting output of `Select-String`.